# How can I get the current view name inside a master layour in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel-4

in Laravel 4 I have a master blade layout and I want to add a class to the html element like 'tpl-home', but I need to know which is the current view name called with View::make.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es" class="tpl-{{Str::slug($currentViewName)}}">
```

Does Laravel provide any function for retrieving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Inside your filters file place:

```
View::composer('*', function($view){

    View::share('view_name', $view->getName());

});
```

Then in your master blade layout you can access it as $view_name.

Comment: How would you do this in Laravel 5?

Comment: This works, but if you use any `@include`'s for partials, those overwrite `view_name` with whatever view was loaded last.

Comment: @Mattias This works by adding it to a service provider

Answer (score 4):

View Composers are a great way to keep/share variables in views, but the names of the views set in routes file are more a fixed value in each view than a variable, that's why, in this case,

I'd rather use `Request::path() == 'viewName'` in Blade like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li{{ Request::path() == 'admin' ? ' class="active"' : '' }}>
    <a href="{{ URL::to('/admin') }}">Admin</a>
  </li>
  <li{{ Request::path() == 'bookings' ? ' class="active"' : '' }}>
    <a href="{{ URL::to('/bookings') }}">Bookings</a>
  </li>
  ...
```

Comment: It's a good technique, but having the path hardcoded in the template would make it harder to refactor.