# Is it possible to get the view / layout name in a Laravel (4) blade template

Tags: php, templates, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a layout in which I want to add classes to the body depending on which view is being displayed, i.e.:

```
<body class="layout-default page-index">
```

I can do this in Twig quite easily (OctoberCMS uses Twig) but I can't see a way to do it with Laravel's Blade templates (which I prefer anyway).

I'd rather not have to pass a variable to every `View::make` with the view name as this seems redundant.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22404727/1903366)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question, very smart way to work with css.
You would use this typically by adding classes to the body tag, or the main container div.

within your routes or filters file:

```
View::composer('*', function($view){

    View::share('view_name', $view->getName());

});
```

Within your view:

```
<?php echo str_replace('.','-',$view_name);?>

<?php echo str_replace('.','-',Route::currentRouteName());?>
```

These should get you everything you need.

Comment: I'm currently using a view composer as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403655/how-can-i-get-the-current-view-name-inside-a-master-layour-in-laravel-4/22404727#22404727 but that's a nice way around, too. I wish this were a bit better documented.

Comment: This actually didn't work for me in blade. I just got `undefined method Illuminate\View\Factory::getName()`.