# Laravel 5 get view name

Tags: php, templates, view, laravel-5

I'm struggling to get the view name in L5. Just as in WP, I'd like to add a specific page name (view name) for styling, like so:

```
<!-- View name: login.blade.php !-->
<div id="page" class="page-login">
    <h1>Inloggen</h1>
</div>

<!-- View name: register.blade.php !-->
<div id="page" class="page-register">
    <h1>Registreren</h1>
</div>
```

In L4 it can be done using composer to share the var across all views ([How can I get the current view name inside a master layour in Laravel 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403655/how-can-i-get-the-current-view-name-inside-a-master-layour-in-laravel-4)). But I only need the view name once for my master layout.

Doing this:

```
<div id="page" class="page-{{ view()->getName() }}">
```

Gives me the following error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\View\Factory::getName()`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your only option is a view composer. What's the problem with that?

Comment: Okay, I thought there was another way, but I'm fine with using a view composer. Thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Update your AppServiceProvider by adding a view composer to the boot method and using '*' to share it with all views:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;    

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('*', function($view){
            $view_name = str_replace('.', '-', $view->getName());
            view()->share('view_name', $view_name);
        });

    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

`{{$view_name}}` will be made available to your blade templates.

Comment: How would you return this value back to the boot function @spedley ?  I'm wanting to do this so that I can alter the returned value and return it via a separate view->share command.

Comment: @AdamJones - If I understand your question correctly, I think (with your own custom mods) the example code in the answer should already largely do what you need. It takes the returned value '$view->getName()', alters it (eg: changes 'partials.help' to 'partials-help') and shares it with all the views via view()->share('view_name', $view_name). I'm not sure I understand the need to return it to the boot function.

Comment: Thank for this, $view_name is callable in every page {{$view_name}} big help

Answer (score 0):

Based on @motto answer i was able to get the blade file in blink of an eye.

`find()` is a function in the `ViewFileFinder` class that search for views , paths and namespaces.

then explode the return to get the file name.
`last()` is a helper function in laravel.

```
@php
   $view1 = View::getFinder()->find('login');
   $page_login= last(explode('/', $view)); // this return login.blade.php
   $view2 = View::getFinder()->find('register');
   $page_register= last(explode('/', $view)); // this return register.blade.php
@endphp

@if($page_login == 'login.blade.php')
<!-- View name: login.blade.php !-->
<div id="page" class="page-login">
    <h1>Inloggen</h1>
</div>
@endif

@if($page_register == 'register.blade.php')
<!-- View name: register.blade.php !-->
<div id="page" class="page-register">
    <h1>Registreren</h1>
</div>
@endif
```