# How to get how many times a view was included in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Is there any way to tell how many times a view has been included in blade, inside the view?

e.g.:

```
@if(thisViewWasIncluded())
    <div ... />
@else
    <div class="..." ... />
@endif
```

Comment: Debugbar does it, I'm diggin their repo

Comment: Wow thats what I call devotion :D
Thanks @aaron0207!

Comment: @aaron0207 No, Debugbar only shows the views that were rendered at all

Comment: But maybe we can use the same method to fetch all views and then filter and count them

Comment: @aaron0207 Well, the OP only want's to know whether a specific view is (conditionally) included or not. I can't see how you'd filter views for this criterion.

Comment: Excuse me sir, but where do you read this question? Maybe I'm blind but actually I'm reading:  How to get how many times a view was included in Laravel?. What I'm trying is to create an array like this `array('view_name' => $count)`. Anyways I'm doing it for fun since your answer seems to provide a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the way I actually managed to do this:

I created a View Composer that attaches the View name to a ViewBag class like this:

```
view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
    ViewBag::attach($view->getName());
});
```

Then I created a `viewBag()` helper function that returns the ViewBag instance that contains all information attached. Now it can be used like so:

```
<h1>
    Auth.Login was included: 
    {{ viewBag()->count('auth.login') }} times
</h1>
```

Now I can also do stuff like:

```
@if(viewBag()->contains('auth.login'))
    hello
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible through an easy function call like that. But if you include your view conditionally (for example through the `includeWhen()` function), you could just check the value of the conditional.

Example:

```
@includeWhen($boolean, 'view.name', ['some' => 'data'])
@if($boolean)
//View included
@else
//View not included
@endif
```

Comment: thanks!
And can you get the view name inside the view programmatically?

Comment: @kristófbaján No problem! Yeah, you can do that :) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458845/laravel-5-get-view-name