# Get folder name of laravel view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have `/app/resources/views/category/index.blade.php`

And in `index.blade.php` I want to know that it was in the folder "**category**".  Is there a laravel function that will return the path of the current view?

Something like:

```
 $folder = view_path(); // "/category"
```

Comment: PHP natively supports `__FILE__` and `__DIR__`

Comment: In this case __FILE__ and __DIR__ do not work.  They return always return the storage/views cache directory

Comment: Ah, ok.  That makes sense since blade views are compiled.

Comment: Does it make sense for your controller to pass the category since it obviously would have that information anyways.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458845/laravel-5-get-view-name

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers)

> View composers are callbacks or class methods that are called when a
>   view is rendered. If you have data that you want to be bound to a view
>   each time that view is rendered, a view composer can help you organize
>   that logic into a single location.

In the file `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`, edit the `public function boot()` method

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot(Application $app)
{

  view()->composer('*', function($view) {
       // get view paths from config - this is absolute path
       $configPaths      = config('view.paths');

       // get view's full path
       $absoluteViewPath = $view->getPath();

       foreach($configPaths as $configPath) {
         // see if current view's path matches path from config
         // both are absolute paths
         if ( strpos($absoluteViewPath, $configPath) !== false ) {
           $path = str_replace($configPath, '', $absoluteViewPath);

           // remove view name - from last position of `/`
           $dir  = substr($path, 0, strrpos( $path, '/'));

           // attach to views
           view()->share('view_folder', $dir);

           // view matched, stop looking
           break;
         }

       }

       // if nothing was found
       view()->share('view_folder', '');
   });
}
```

After this, in any blade template you will now have access to a variable

`{{ $view_folder }}`

Answer (score -1):

Add the namespace at the top of your class: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;`
run:

```
$files = File::allFiles(resource_path('views'));

  foreach ($files as $file) {
     echo (string) $file, "\n";
  }
```

or your case:

```
$files = File::files(resource_path('views/category'));

foreach ($files as $path => $value) {
     echo $value->getPath() . "\n";
}
```