# Get the file name BLADE of LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

is it possible to know which BLADE page you are on? I would like to include a different menu where my VIEW is the MAIN, how can I do this in the template? I check if it is my MAIN and add my different menu there if in case. example:  @if(config('page.layout') == 'top-nav'); 
Is that possible? but with another code, of course

Comment: You should take a look at components/slots: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#components-and-slots

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36022521/470749 shows how to get view name in Laravel Blade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to pick up which file or URL my BLADE was, I got it this way:

```
      @if(Route::current()->getName() == 'name') .... 
         ##codeHTML
      @endif
```

Comment: If you want it even cleaner, you can just use `@if(Route::is('name'))`

Answer (score 3):

To me it seems like you are thinking with the wrong way. You should know what(which controller, which method) has loaded that view instead of what is this view. And you can pass control variables from there if you want.

In you question, the example you have shown:

`@if(config('adminlte.layout') == 'top-nav')`

So `top-nav` is coming form config `adminlte.layout` which has no relation with blade template or anything else. You can definitely do that if you set your config file based on your intention.

Comment: example:  @if(config('adminlte.layout') == 'top-nav');  I want to get my page, this is possible?