# Pull out View name for a particular Route - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

Is there any way to take out the view name used for a route?

I have pulled out all the GET routes from web.php using

```
array_keys(\Route::getRoutes()->getRoutesByMethod()['GET']);
```

With the list like:

```
1. /
2. /users
3. /admin
....
```

I would like to get the view name for routes like so

```
/ => home.blade.php
/users => users.blade.php
/admin => adminPanel.blade.php
```

Comment: *"Is there any way [...]"* - Out of the box, I don't believe so, simply because routes aren't inherently tied to a specific view; they can return a view, a json response, a redirect, etc. It's all based on the controller that handles it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

Comment: No problem! You might be able to get the Controller method that handles it, but in my testing, trying to log a single `Route` class actually timedout my system, so you'd have to dig into the api reference: https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html, see if any of the methods there can reveal any useful information. You'd have to remove `array_keys()` though to actually get at the `Route` class.

Comment: Sure, will look into it.

Comment: You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458845/laravel-5-get-view-name)

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure can you try this and tell me what did you got??

```
   $route_name =[] ;
  foreach (Route::getRoutes()->getRoutes() as $route)
       {
          $action = $route->getAction();
           if (array_key_exists('as', $action)) {
              $route_name [] = $action['as'];
          }
       }
     dd($route_name) ;
```