# Display name of current blade file

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to have an h1 tag that displays the current file name.

For example, in the blade file "index.blade.php", I would like to have an h1 tag that displays "index.blade.php".

I have tried doing using `{{__FILE__}}` but that prints out the cached blade file and not the actual name

```
// index.blade.php

<h1>{{__FILE__}}</h1>
```

**Result:**
project/storage/framework/views/eweijo29398hr23.php

**Desired Result:** /index.blade.php

Comment: Not a blade expert and also not sure if this is working, but can you try `{{basename(__FILE__)}}` ?  [PHP basename function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

Comment: `basename()` won't work as it gets the cached filename instead of the source

Answer (score 0):

Here is still working solution:
[How can I get the current view name inside a master layour in Laravel 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403655/how-can-i-get-the-current-view-name-inside-a-master-layour-in-laravel-4)

```
View::composer('*', function($view){

    View::share('view_name', $view->getName());

});
```

Answer (score -1):

```php
@php
app('events')->listen('composing:*', function ($view, $data = []) {
    echo last(explode('/', $data[0]->getEngine()->getCompiler()->getPath()));
});
@endphp
```

It's slightly messy but works!